# git credential-osxkeychain get hangs

Tags: macos, git, credentials, keychain

If I execute `git credential-osxkeychain get`, it just hangs when it should return information regarding what credentials are stored in the keychain. Is there a way to make this work?

I am using OS X 10.15.5

```
$ git credential-osxkeychain
usage: git credential-osxkeychain <get|store|erase>

$ git --version
git version 2.27.0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of `git credential-*` helpers are meant to be used internally by git itself and follow a specific interface.

When the helper is run with the `get` subcommand, it *waits for input on stdin* and expects to read a series of "key=value" lines. For example, `host=github.com`. This is how git tells the helper *which* credentials are needed.

When you run a program directly in a terminal, its stdin is just connected to keyboard input. After the first <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress, the tool is already running but waiting for keyboard input, exactly like tools such as `cat` or `sed` would.

After the second keypress, the program *reads an empty line* and treats it as an "end of input" indicator, i.e. that no more key=value lines will be entered. At this point it searches the keychain and finds whichever entry it thinks matches your "provided" filter.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :
**Deleting your credentials via the command line**

```
$ git credential-osxkeychain erase
host=github.com
protocol=https
> [Press Return]
```

If it's successful, nothing will print out. To test that it works, try and clone a private repository from GitHub.com. If you are prompted for a password, the keychain entry was deleted.